# javascript call submit for postback

Tags: javascript, php, onclick, postback

I've read a lot of googling forums, but my simple sample still doesn't work. That is why I ask you to help me with my prob. I have page1 and page 2. I also have for debugging button (submit) in page1 and page2 with function header($direct). This part works and I have full understanding. But I cann't call full postback via javascript function. I don't know where is my fault. This is my union code for page1:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['btn']))
{
   header('Location: page2.php');
}
elseif (isset ($_POST['btn2']))
{
   header('Location: page2.php');
}
?>

<h1>This is page 1</h1>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>">
   <input type="submit" name="btn" value="submit: goto page2"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="button" name="btn2" id ="btn2" value="button: goto page2" onclick="postback();" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
   function postback(){
 var f = document.getElementById('form1');
f.submit();
   }
</script>
```

I want to call full postback without ajax because with ajax I have no problems.
In last example I tried to call javascript postback with selection object and I couldn't any problems with it. But now, when I try to use simple button onclick event it still doesn't work. why? I hope you understand my English and point me to my faults. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

input type button will not show value in post

if you want to pass anything into post
try input type=hidden

Comment: you are right. It isn't possible to transfer button value through postback, but with hidden field it is posssible. So, in js I createElement('input') and add some value to it which I call from php. And as result this code starts to work.

Comment: in that case returns "" that means use the same file, doesn't it?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<input type="submit" name="btn2" id ="btn2" value="button: goto page2" onclick="postback();" />
```

make type as submit
 it worked for me

Comment: if use type="submit" then no need to call onclick event via javascript

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your  statement.  Your action statement is: php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ... You need to put echo in there so PHP knows to echo the variable: echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']

It's always the little things.

Comment: yes, you are right, that in this case <?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?> returns "" instead of php-file destination. of cause it needs to add echo, but it doesn't solve the problem